# Java - Listen/identify a single mouse-wheel scroll event only?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a `JScrollPane` with a `JPanel` added to it. I want every scroll of the mouse wheel to scroll the panel to the location of a certain component.

I can cycle through each component just fine to find it's location. I know how to scroll to that location. The problem is, I cannot find a way to cycle through only *once* every mouse-scroll.

Here's what I've tried. I've added a `ChangeListener` to the `JScrollPane`'s viewport, i.e

```
scrollpane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
```

I get three console `ChangeEvent`s for every mouse-wheel scroll, this is bad (obviously) because I am over-scrolling, and I see no way to identify that the type of `ChangeEvent` was a mouse-wheel scroll so as to only get one event per mouse-wheel scroll.

The second thing I tried was an `AdjustmentListener`, i.e

```
scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
```

Identical problem. Three console `AdjustmentEvent`s per mouse-wheel scroll. No way to identify if it was a mouse-wheel scroll that triggered the event (I tried a bunch of different `getSource()` and `getID()` methods for both types of event, couldn't get any to do anything useful).

So I ask you guys, am I missing something obvious or is it going to be a bit harder than I had thought to identify a single mouse-wheel scroll?

Comment: Have you tried a [`MouseWheelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelListener.html)? ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html)): "*However, to create a custom component to be used inside a scroll pane you may need to customize its scrolling behavior*" - sounds exactly like what you need.

Comment: Doing so now, definitely looks like what I need .. guess I was missing something obvious, didn't know this type of listener existed!